# Get canonical link

Tags: permalinks, redirect, urls

Hi I know `get_permalink` returns the URL. Some of my posts are redirected and at the same time I update the canonical link to the redirected post URL - (normally relates to post updates).

Is there a function I can use to return the canonical URL of a post if it has one rather than it's 'permalink' URL? I use Yoast SEO to edit canonical URLs and also apply redirects. I want to use the 'canonical permalink' in a function.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, terminologically permalink _is_ canonical permalink in modern WordPress. Could you elaborate (maybe with example) why/how do you consider them to be different?

Comment: Yes no problem. Yoast SEO allows posts to be redirected to avoid duplicate content and at the same time the canonical link can be set to the redirected post. On my site take this archive page http://skipology.com/category/iphoneography-workflow/ - the first post http://skipology.com/creating-foggy-atmosphere-superimpose-iphone-photography-video/ redirects to the second post (it is an update) http://skipology.com/atmospheric-photography-fog-cant-find-create/ - get_permalink returns the first post URL but I need to return the link I have set as canonical that it redirects to (second link).

Answer (score 3):

Since WP 4.6 there has been a core function for this: `wp_get_canonical_url()`

Call it with a post ID to get that post's canonical URL, or in the loop without a post ID to get the current post's canonical URL.